# Docker Network Understanding

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a 3 containers architecture for a web app (front-end, back-end, database). I created two networks one for the back (database + back-end), the other for the front (front + back). I am using compose to start the services.

I can't access my front container from my host even though I published a port.

Am I missing something to make it work ?

Here is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
services:
  api:
    image: ruby:3.1.2
    command: sh -c "rm -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle install && rails s"
    working_dir: /app
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - back
      - front
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ../api
        target: /app
  web:
    image: node
    working_dir: /app
    command: sh -c "yarn install && yarn build && yarn dev"
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      - front
      - host
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ../frontend
        target: /app
    ports:
      - "8000:5173"
  database:
    image: keinos/sqlite3
    networks:
      - back
    expose:
      - "3306"
    volumes:
      - citrine-db:/db
networks:
  back:
    driver: bridge
  front:
    driver: bridge
  host:
volumes:
  citrine-db:
```

Comment: How are you trying to access your service (and what exactly happens when you try)?

Comment: I get a reset connection when I try connecting on localhost:8000.

Comment: Are you certain that your `web` container is healthy? Does it work if you connect directly to the container ip address on port 5173?

Comment: When I execute a curl localhost:5173 from inside the web container I get something relevant.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but if you try the same thing on your host using the container ip, do you see the same result? I am trying to differentiate between "application configuration issue" vs "host network configuration issue".

Comment: Don't apologize, thank you for helping. I get a connection refused when I try accesing ip_address:5173

Comment: This setup doesn't seem like it's really "using Docker" at all: you're using unmodified `ruby` and `node` images to run code that only lives on the host system.  Your network environment will be much simpler if you run the code directly on the host as well.  The Bundler `vendor` and npm `node_modules` directories will still give you isolated library installations.  Do you actually need Docker here?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying by not using Docker. My application is contained is it not ? I went for this configuration, first for testing Docker, second I thought it might be a good idea, to separate the different component of my app into different containers. How would you modify the images. I'm open to advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this:

> I get a connection refused when I try accesing ip_address:5173

It *sounds like* your application is only listening on the localhost address (`127.0.0.1`). You need it to listen on "all addresses" (`0.0.0.0`). This is why you're able to connect to `localhost:5173` from inside the container, but connections from outside the container are failing.